# Embarcadero: How to use TBase64Encoding's EncodeBytesToString method

Tags: c++, encoding, c++builder, firemonkey, c++builder-xe8

I am attempting to convert an array of bytes to a base64 encoded String using the `EncodeBytesToString` method of the `TBase64Encoding` class.  The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding.EncodeBytesToString) for `EncodeBytesToString` states:

> "Returns a string with the input array of bytes encoded up to the specified number of bytes."

Therefore, I attempted to encode my byte array like so:

```
TFile * File = new TFile();

TBytes Bytes = File->ReadAllBytes("D:\\Sample.pdf");

TBase64Encoding * Encoder = new TBase64Encoding();

String EncodedBytes = Encoder->EncodeBytesToString(Bytes, Bytes.Length);
```

However, I get the following error:

`E2285 Could not find a match for 'TNetEncoding::EncodeBytesToString(TByteDynArray,int)'`

I am confused, as the documentation seems to say that I should pass a `TBytes` object and an `int` into this function.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
String __fastcall BytesToBase64( TByteDynArray _ArrayIn )
{
    TBase64Encoding * Encoding = new TBase64Encoding( 64, '\n' );
    String Result = Encoding->EncodeBytesToString( &_ArrayIn[0], _ArrayIn.High );
    delete Encoding;
    return Result;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TByteDynArray __fastcall Base64ToBytes( String _64String )
{
    TByteDynArray My64Bytes = _64String.BytesOf();
    return TNetEncoding::Base64->Decode(&My64Bytes[0], My64Bytes.High);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding` provides the static property `Base64` to retrieve an instance of `TNetEncoding` for base64 encoding.

So this will also work:

```c++
String __fastcall BytesToBase64(TByteDynArray _ArrayIn)
{
    return TNetEncoding::Base64->EncodeBytesToString(&_ArrayIn[0], _ArrayIn.High);
}
```